# Convert numbers to hours

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to do simple "total worked hours" calculator.

I have a textbox that I want to write in, say, `1.30`, which would be 1 hour and 30 minutes. I have another textbox where I would put the same `1.30`, and then I want to a label to add them and show 3 hours.

However, I can't find the right code to convert numbers to hours, and instead it shows 2.6. How can I make it show 3 hours?

Here is my code

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Label1.Text = Val(TextBox1.Text) + Val(TextBox2.Text)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        TextBox1.Text = My.Settings.SaveTextBox()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        My.Settings.SaveTextBox = TextBox1.Text()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to take `1.30 hours` as the input? I would think `1:30` or `1.5` are better representations of that time. If the string `hours` must be in the input, then do you also want to handle `minutes` i.e. `90 minutes`?

Comment: In your world 2.6 hours = 3 hours. So wherever you do that conversion you need to convert .6 to 1. You are missing that

Comment: Does `1.3` equal `1.30` or `1.03`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `NumericUpDown` will save you having to check if the user really entered a number in a text box. Set the `NumericUpDownMinutes` to a maximum of 59 in the properties window. The `PadLeft` adds a leading zero to single digit minutes.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Hours = NumericUpDownHours.Value.ToString
    Dim Minutes = NumericUpDownMinutes.Value.ToString
    lblTotal.Text = $"{Hours}.{Minutes.PadLeft(2, "0"c)}"
End Sub
```

To get rounded hours

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim Hours = NumericUpDownHours.Value
    Dim Minutes = NumericUpDownMinutes.Value
    Dim RoundedHours = CInt(Hours + Minutes / 60)
    lblRoundedTotal.Text = RoundedHours.ToString
End Sub
```

Comment: Thx, it works now.